# Safari doesn't remember desktop notifications after quit and launch

Tags: safari, mojave, notifications

I opened a couple of sites that ask for desktop notifications, like WhatsApp and Telegram. I allowed that, and i even see those sites in the 'Websites -> Notifications' panel in Preferences. I've also pinned those tabs.

However, every time i quit Safari and launch it again all these sites ask for those desktop notifications permissions again, even though they are listed in the preferences panel. I don't know what's going on. Does this have something to do with the fact that i pinned the tabs? Or is there some other privacy setting that i'm not aware of?

I'm running Safari 12.1.2 on Mojave 10.14.6.

Comment: I could see that on chat.SE itself. I thought it was a site issue. and now when I think of it, slack also fails to send notifications. Safari 12.1.1 OS 10.14.5

Comment: @ankii yes, i saw it with Slack, Telegram and WhatsApp, so it's definitely not a site issue.